# How to route inbound traffic on one interface to another interface in the same machine?

Tags: networking, iptables

I have searched the forums, but can't find a solution that addresses my use-case exactly. I need to do this on a remote machine and so don't have a lot of latitude to get this wrong (and possibly lock myself out of the box).

The remote PC has two physical interfaces: eth0 and eth1.
eth0 IP is 192.168.0.4/255.255.255.0 while eth1 is 192.168.1.60/255.0.0.0

I need to route/forward inbound TCP traffic on port 502 received on eth0 to 192.168.1.50 port 502 (this is a remote device accessible via the eth1 network). I need to do the same above for UDP on port 30718.

I have read the iptables How To but am not sure whether to use INPUT or FORWARD etc.

Any help on how to use iptables to do this would be very much appreciated!

Thanks,

Jean-Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot help you doing this with iptables, but the following does the trick:

For TCP you could use `redir`:

```
redir --lport=502 --cport=502 --caddr=192.168.1.50 [--debug]
```

You can add `--laddr` to bind it to your interface. Else it would accept connections from any interface.

For UDP you could use `socat`:

```
sudo socat UDP4-RECVFROM:30718,fork UDP4-SENDTO:192.168.1.50:10161
```

Manuals see here:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/filan.1.html

http://linux.die.net/man/1/redir

Comment: Hey - many thanks for the feedback! I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: I was told that I am not allowed to use other tools besides iptables for this requirement. :-/ I much appreciate the help though!

Comment: then have a look here: http://serverfault.com/questions/140622/how-can-i-port-forward-with-iptables